# Jinja2 Exceptions - Cannot find attribute

Tags: html, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

Working on a problem in Flask/ Python. Had a few of these errors pop up and I've been able to squash them as they arise; however, this one I cannot seem to get to the bottom of.

I have a simple form which allows users to login.

But each time I load the page I am greeted with this error:

**jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'shop.forms.LoginForm object' has no attribute 'submit'**

Below is the code that I am working with, thanks in advance.

p.s. I have seen similar posts regarding the hidden_tag() attribute, but the fixes suggested are not working for this scenario.

## routes.py

```
import os
from flask import render_template, url_for, request, redirect, flash
from shop import app, db
from shop.models import Author, Book, User
from shop.forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm
from flask_login import login_user, current_user, logout_user, login_required


@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
form = LoginForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
    if user is not None and user.verify_password(form.password.data):
        login_user(user)
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
return render_template('login.html', title='Login', form=form)
```

## forms.py

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
sumbit = SubmitField('Login')
```

## login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>



{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}

<form method="POST" action="">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    <div class="">
        {{ form.email.label }} {{ form.email}}
    </div>
    <div class="">
    {{ form.password.label }} {{ form.password}}
    </div>
    <div class="">
        {{ form.submit() }}
    </div>
</form>

{% endblock content %}

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Removing the () from submit doesn't solve the issue. Just removes the instance of the button entirely from the template. See below:

[image: Screenshot of form on website.]

Answer (score 1):

Change `form.submit()` to `form.submit` and it will show the submit button in template.

Here is an example of using `flask_wtf` for a login form.

### Example of using Flask wtform:

`app.py`:

```
from flask import render_template, url_for, request, redirect, flash, Flask
from forms import LoginForm

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'secret key'

@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_email = form.email.data
        user_password = form.password.data
        if user_email and user_password:
            return "{} - {}".format(user_email, user_password)
    return render_template('login.html', title='Login', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`forms.py`:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Login')
```

`login.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="POST" action="">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    <div class="">
        {{ form.email.label }} {{ form.email }}
    </div>
    <div class="">
        {{ form.password.label }} {{ form.password }}
    </div>
    <div class="">
        {{ form.submit }}
    </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

Get request of `login` route:

[image: Get request of login route]

Post request of `login` route:

[image: Post request of login route]

**Updates:**

`requirements.txt`:

```
Click==7.0
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
Werkzeug==0.15.0
WTForms==2.2.1
```

I successfully run this code both in my machine and in [c9.io](https://c9.io/).

Get request for `/login` route (before submitting the form):

[image: before submitting the login form]

After submitting the form:

[image: after submitting the login form]

Comment: unfortunately I tried this and nothing came of it. Simply doesn't display the button now. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Matt, good to hear that you resolved the issue. In my case, I can get the login button using this code. The login button is shown both in my local machine and c9.io. I have updated answer showing that.

Comment: I am using slightly different versions for my imports, I am also using Flask-Login to manage the login system on my end. That might be where our discrepancy is.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue solved!

I didn't spell ***submit*** correctly in forms.py

Simple clerical error that cost me 2 hours.